# Simulate an Excel worksheet on HTML page

Tags: html, excel

I am working on a page where visitors need to copy-paste hundreds of rows from an Excel spreadsheet on to the page. The easier way to do it is to display a text area and parse the different columns.

But is there a way to display something like a spreadsheet? That will be more user friendly. I tried CKEditor for an option like this, but it doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can display a excel spreedsheet in asp code either c# or vb.

Try this link for displaying Spreedsheets,
[Displaying Spreedsheet on webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms524873%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)